# How to pass variable in gdscript to c #

Tags: c#, godot

How to passing gdscript variable values ​​to c # and vice versa.

I have nothing else to say

Comment: I do.. What did you tried?

Comment: pass values ​​from a gdscript to c #

Comment: If you have a variable that you can access from GDScript, you should be able to access it from C#. If you are having trouble, it suggests you are doing something unusual. Are you trying to call a C# function from GDScript (pass the variable as a parameter)? Are you trying to access a GDScript property from C#? What do you mean by "pass"? Is your C# script attached to a node in the scene tree? Is your GDScript script attached to a node in the scene tree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me.

Node setup:

[image]

CS code:

```
using Godot;
using System;

public class Node : Godot.Node
{

    public int b = 2;

    public override void _Ready()
    {
        GD.Print(GetTree().Root.GetChild(0).Get("a"));
    }


}
```

GD script code:

```
extends Node2D


var a = 2

func _ready():
    print(get_child(0).get("b"))
```

Just make sure that the variables are of the same type (int in this case).

Comment: Thanks, you saved me!! is possible use singleton? C# -> gdscript | gdscript ->C#?